# How to build tiles and display them without georeferencing?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, tiles, display, gdal2tiles

When I work with georeferenced image (GeoTiff) I can use `gdal2tiles.py` to build tiles and generate `googlemaps.html`, `leaflet.html`, `openlayers.html`, etc. which I can upload to server and share with other users.

But what if I want to just created tiles of big tiff image (not geotiff image for example [image of moon](https://superuser.com/questions/254677/what-software-works-well-for-viewing-massive-tiff-images-on-windows-7)) and share it without georeferencing to any map? How it can be done?